# NetBeans and the Invisible jUnit Library

Tags: netbeans, junit, netbeans-7.2

I installed jUnit using the normal NetBeans installer but when I try to open a project that uses jUnit, I get a dialog box that says I have to resolve missing references. In addition, when I tried to find the jUnit library, I noticed that it wasn't in the list of libraries.

I have already tried installing the NetBeans jUnit plugin.

What must I do to get jUnit working?

Context:

- Windows 7 SP1 64-bit edition
- NetBeans 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the Project type you are using.

**Ant**:
Right click on on the `Libraries` folder and select `Add Library...`.
A new window will appear where you can choose a JUnit version to add.

**Maven**:
Open `Project Files`/`pom.xml`.
Declare a JUnit dependency like that:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, jUnit is not listed in the Add Library dialog.